# sbt multi-module project: dependence between projects

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to Scala, so I hope this question is not too naive.

Suppose I have a [multi-module sbt-project](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Multi-Project.html) and there is a dependence between projects.

```
  lazy val core = (project in file("core")).
    settings( ... )

  lazy val utils = (project in file("utils")).
    settings( ... ).dependsOn(core)
```

The question, does `.dependsOn(core)` mean that if I do `projects utils; compile` it is going to `compile` the `core` beforehand (and use its latest version)?

I am asking this, since in practice I don't see this behavior (and I want it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `aggregate` method. Like this:

```
lazy val utils = (project in file("utils")).
  settings( ... ).dependsOn(core).aggregate(core)
```

The aggregate method here causes all tasks run on `utils` to also be run on `core` (update, etc...). If you want to disable a task from running on an aggregated project you can check out [the documentation here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Aggregation)

Comment: Thanks! so added the `aggregate` option and it worked; but what happens if now inside `utils` I do publish local? is the `publish`ed package gonna include `core`?

Comment: The published package will always include core because you depend on it. If you leave it like this, the `publish` command will be run on `core` as well. You can disable specific commands from being run on other projects. I will update my answer with this information and a link to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should see this behavior (and I do see it in practice). As the linked documentation says (note that the roles of `util` and `core` are opposite there: `core` depends on `util`):

> This also creates an ordering between the projects when compiling them; util must be updated and compiled before core can be compiled

Comment: How about `aggregate` setting that other answer says? What do you think about that?

Comment: Also I don't see why you say the dependance is opposite; like here in the documentation says 
"`foo dependsOn(bar)` means that the compile configuration in `foo` depends on the compile configuration in `bar`."

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html

Comment: With the same logic `utils` depends on `core`. Am I correct?

Comment: @Daniel Their example has `lazy val core = project.dependsOn(util)`.

Comment: @Daniel And `aggregate` should not be required, but yes, it will have the effect that compiling `utils` will also compile `core`; I don't know if it provides any additional guarantees about ordering, though, so it could compile files in the `utils` directory first and `core` afterwards if `dependsOn` wasn't enough.